# How to filter javascript from specific urls in HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, automation, htmlunit

HtmlUnit takes lot of time to execute javascript, i would like to know if its possible to make HtmlUnit not to load javascript from url regex filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, you can't only disable javascript as a whole (probably you already know it):

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavascriptEnable(false);
```

but you can use a [ScriptPreProcessor](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ScriptPreProcessor.html) the javascript, and erase what you don't want:

```
webClient.setScriptPreProcessor(new ScriptPreProcessor() {

        @Override
        public String preProcess(HtmlPage htmlPage, String sourceCode, String sourceName, int lineNumber, HtmlElement htmlElement) {
            if (match...)
            return "";
        }
    });
```

Comment: How would I do this when using HtmlUnitDriver?  Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303430/blacklist-and-whitelist-urls-in-htmlunitdriver